# Can I update QBO item inventory amounts and item prices with API without causing issues?

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am playing with the consolibyte / quickbooks-php Devkit to integrate dolibarr's inventory data with our company's QBO.  I am not having coding issues at this point, but am wondering if there are any stability issues within QBO if I update stock amounts and item prices from my application.  Will I need to update meta.date information or other info so that QBO continues to work properly after updates?  Also, if I insert inventory items, are there similar considerations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any update in Quickbooks entities will cause metadata lastupdatedtime to update, you need not explicitly update that info. Just send the correct synctoken, Id and metadata of existing object and do an update for whatever tag/data you want to change. Rest API will take care of.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!  I will proceed :)